# Given the equation $x^2-14x+m=0$, where m is a positive integer. If $p_1,p_2$ are roots, then find the value of $K=(p_1+p_2)^2+2p_1p_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving, integers

Given the equation $x^2-14x+m=0$, where $m$ is a positive integer. If roots $p_1, p_2$ are distinct, positive, prime integers, then find the value of $K=(p_1+p_2)^2+2p_1p_2$

I tried to solve this question using the Vieta formulas and said $p_1+p_2=14$ and $p_1p_2=m$. But I got stuck there, I assume that you have to work out what the value of $m$ is, but I can't manage to work it out. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: Question : Are p1 and p2 necessarily distinct?

Comment: @IshraaqParvez yes, I'm editing it now

Comment: we may do it directly by trial and error as $p_1$ and $p_2$ are positive. We can get either (3,11) or (7,7)

Comment: Is this a past AIME question? (AIME 2021 questions are not allowed here until after all test sessions are finished Mar. 18.)

Comment: @aschepler no it isn't, or at least I don't think it is, I found it in an old stack of papers, from back in early 2000s

Comment: "I assume that you have to work out what the value of m"  I don't see how you can.  You correctly have if that $(p_1+p_2)^2 + 2p_1p_2 = 14^2 +2m$.

Comment: @fleablood Knowing that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are positive primes and $p_1+p_2 = 14$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if p1 and p2 are distinct, then there is only a single pair of positive primes that satisfies the condition $p_1+p_2=14$, and these are $3$ and $11$.

Else, if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are not distinct, the question could have two possible answers, because both $7$ and $7$ as well as $3$ and $11$ satisfy the equation.

Can you go ahead now?

Comment: Yes, thank you very mcuh

Answer (score 2):

Well the roots of $x^2 - 14x + m = (x^2 -14x +49) + (m-49) = (x-7)^2 -(49-m)$ are $7 \pm \sqrt{49-m}$.

So $p_1+ p_2 = 14$ and $p_1p_2 = 49 - (49-m) = m$.

So $m$ is the product of two distinct prime so that $49 - m$ is perfect square.  Well, quit worrying and start scurrying.

The perfect squares less than $49$ are $1,4,9, 16, 25, 36$ so $m = 48,45, 40, 33,24,13$ and of those the only one that is product of two distinct primes are $33=3\times 11$

So $(p_1 + p_1)^2 + 2p_1p_2 = 14^2 + 2\cdot 33$.

=====

Argh a dope slap to me for getting $49-m$ must be a perfect square but not getting that $14$ is the sum of distinct primes.  It is still trial and error, but $1+13,2+12,3+11,4+10, 5+9, 8+6, 7+7$ so $3,11$ are the only sum of two primes is an easier trial by error.